DIscord Bot message deleting
I have made a discord bot(with discord.py) that will ping a certain role if there is any new message in a certain channel. But I want the bot to delete the ping immediately. How can I do that ?
I tried to message.delete() but it deletes the main message not the ping.

The quickest way to do this is to set the delete_after parameter when sending your message, which will cause it to be silently deleted in the background after the specified time.
await channel.send("@everyone this is a fake ping", delete_after=0)


Reference: discord.TextChannel.send

